# Unable to add local repository to Eclipse

Tags: svn, repository, local

I created a local repository C:\SVN using TortoiseSVN (Right click on SVN > TortoiseSVN > Create Repository here).

I installed subeclipse 1.0.7 in my Eclipse IDE.

From the SVN Repository Exploring perspective... New > Repository Location, I am trying to add the location file:///C:/SVN to the URL field but I get the following error:

svn: Unable to open an ra_local session to URL
svn: Unable to open repository 'file:///C:/SVN'
svn: Expected FS format '2'; found format '4'

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance,
Nikhil

Answer (score 0):

Try updating your Subclipse to newer version, it should clear the problem.

Answer (score -1):

You do not add a *repository* to Eclipse, but a *working copy*.  You should check out your local repository to a different folder and add that to Eclipse.